# days calculation between two dates on Eclipse Birt Report

Tags: eclipse, birt

Can anyone help me about days calculation on eclipse birt reporting. days calculation between Date today less Pr approved date.

my code goes like this:

sqlText = sqlText + " days (BirtDateTime.today() - days (prstatusappr.changedate) as prapprdate ";

It's not working. please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BirtDateTime class provides functions for multiplication, division, addition, subtraction, and so on. 
you can use it for your purpose.

**BirtDateTime.diffDay("2019-03-19",BirtDateTime.today())**

Ex.
sqlText="Difference is "
sqlText = sqlText+" :" +BirtDateTime.diffDay( "2019-03-19",BirtDateTime.today())

BIRT Field Guide ref.
https://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.birt.doc/birt/ScriptingReference.24.4.html